# Prepare dataframe variogram

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sp

I want to prepare a dataset to make a variogram. But it doesn't work. How can I make a spatialpoints dataset of the x and y column, that are non-numeric?

```
library(sp)
head(data)   

   x       y    R
   ï»¿3695.99 1713.02 1.85
   2    3696.99 1712.98 1.32
   3    3697.99 1712.95 0.92
   4    3699.02 1713.05 0.70
   5    3700.02 1713.01 0.44
   6    3701.02 1712.97 0.26



   > coordinates(data) <- ~ x + y
  Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
   cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create SpatialPointsDataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583606/create-spatialpointsdataframe)

Comment: 'coordinates(df1) <- ~ lng + lat' is not working

Comment: What packages are you using? Where do you expect the function `coordinates` to come from, since the error you show is that that function can't be found?

Comment: @user9931361, welcome to SO! I encourage you to see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for guidelines on writing a question that has the highest likelihood of being answered. Your error message indicates that you have non-numeric coordinates in x or y. Try `class(data$x)` and `class(data$y)` to verify that your data are numeric.

Comment: > class(data$x) gives
[1] "factor""

Comment: Do you have suggestions?